# rotate swf along center

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

i have one swf which looks like below image
[image]

OBJECTIVE:-want to rotate the red colored line swf along center as per given image
[image]

i have conditions like

> x-axis,y axis,x=1,x=y,x=-y

my first two conditions are shown in the images.
for the next three conditions the images are
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You either draw another line, or change the line's location within its shape or sprite to have (0,0) point be in the very center, then you plain rotate the line display object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this either with a matrix translation and rotation, or by finding the objects center, rotating the object, and then translating it back (which is basically the same thing as the matrix technique).

**The matrix way:**

```
var mat:Matrix = spr.transform.matrix;
var bounds:Rectangle = spr.getBounds( spr.parent );
mat.translate( -(bounds.left + bounds.width/2), -(bounds.top + bounds.height/2 ) );
mat.rotate( degree * Math.PI / 180 ); //rotate amount
mat.translate( bounds.left + bounds.width/2, bounds.top + bounds.height/2 );
spr.transform.matrix = mat;
```

**Without matrix:**

```
var bounds:Rectangle = spr.getBounds( spr.parent );
var center:Point = new Point( bounds.x + bounds.width/2, bounds.y + bounds.height/2 );

spr.rotation = degree; //rotate amount

bounds = spr.getBounds( spr.parent );
var newCenter:Point = new Point( bounds.x + bounds.width/2, bounds.y + bounds.height/2 );
spr.x += center.x - newCenter.x;
spr.y += center.y - newCenter.y;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if finding the center is good - it depends on the situation. @subrat71 - keep this in mind, that this will rotate the object finding the middle point of it. If you want to rotate the object based it's original rotating one (0,0 coordinates) -> just use object.rotation = 180 :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov your comment is confusing. The user's question is to rotate the line along the center. Although both of my implementations are rotating using the objects center, they could be easily adjusted to rotate from any given point (although he has a square 1,1 ratio shown so my implementation works as expected). Your comment seems to be solidifying the answer. Lastly I have no idea how setting the `object.rotation = 180` solves this problem.

Comment: Your implementation will actually MOVE the object around, and as I said - it depends if someone would like to do that. If the orientation point is 0,0 - there is no such need of all those calculations, simple rotate will do the work :)

_Display objects can be rotated using the rotation property._

Comment: @AndreyPopov I am very aware of how rotation works. At (0,0) orientation, the object rotation will not have the effect the user is asking for. Also only the second implementation actually translates the object as opposed to "rotates", and both implementations the translation calculation is clearly not visible.

Comment: Hm, maybe you're talking about the mistake I've done and written 180 instead of 90? :) Yes, it should be `object.rotation = 90;`

If no - since you know what rotation does, I'm not sure how you can still say rotation won't have the desired effect. It WILL rotate the object. I don't have time to argue, I just wanted to point out that your implementation would move the object around (either it's `x` and `y`, or it's internal content). If he wants to do so - ok. Otherwise - not ok :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov i tried object.rotation = 180;...It rotates , but not as per my requirment... i think matrix will be more use full